# To dial a ' 8 800 333 68 48' used UIApplication.shared.open(, completionHandler:), but it dials a different number." +8 80 333 68 48"

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

```
let urlString = "8 800 333 68 48"
if let phoneURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: ("tel://" + urlString..addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))){
            UIApplication.shared.open(phoneURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            print("* Tapped on number *")

        }
```

[Alert showing a different number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSdkx.png)

Comment: Does your phone number contain a country code? If so it should probably be "+8 800 333 68 48" or use hyphens instead spaces in the string. And why use NSURL instead of URL?

Comment: Should be "+7 800 333 68 48" for Russia.

Comment: The number is a website hotline number. On tap of which I should be call the number.

Comment: In what country is the number located? 880, your first three digits, represents Bangladesh. The second 0 is being dropped as it is not necessary when you have a country code preceding the number.

Comment: Its Akzonobel Russia markets Hotline number shown in their website. In android device on tapping on this same number its dealing the whole number & 0 is not getting omitted. And also of there is some other number at the fourth place apart from 0, its not getting dropped off.